# What image was in the Autostereogram?

Tags: book-of-mythicality, rhett-mclaughlin, link-neal

In a part of the *Book of Mythicality* by Rhett and Link, in the chapter about picking a fight (I believe), there's a couple of pages dedicated to an [Autostereogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram).  I've never been very good at these and I was unable to see the image.

What was the image?  Why was this particular image chosen?

Comment: Any chance you could include an image in this post (e.g. a photo of the relevant pages in your book)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor i'll try and remember to take a pic tonight

Comment: do snapshots of autostereograms still work?  Probably yes, but do try and get the pages as flat and as parallel to the lens as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s the “ANGER ILLUSION” from *Rhett & Link’s Book of Mythicality*:

> [image: Pages 96-97]
>
> There are times when you find yourself in the midst of a confrontation, and if you don’t stop and cool off, you’re destined to get into trouble. We have provided the above image. If you stare at it long enough (crossing your eyes helps), you’ll calm down.

The next page has a flow-chart, titled “CHOOSE YOUR OWN CONFRONTATION”:

> [image: Page 98]

But what does that minuscule text at the bottom left say?

> [image: Detail of page 98]
>
> NOTE ABOUT PREVIOUS PAGE: THE ANGER ILLUSION DID NOT CONTAIN A HIDDEN IMAGE. SORRY IF WE MADE YOU ANGRY AGAIN.

(They were not actually sorry.)

Comment: oh, that's awesome!  i totally didn't catch that little blurb at the bottom!  thank you!